# Dependencia en Javascript

Tags: javascript, phonegap, framework7

Estoy usando `Framework7` para hacer una aplicación móvil con `phonegap`. Mi duda surge con `javascript`, en el que soy totalmente novato.
Mi pregunta es si puedo importar un `.js` desde otro `.js` por ejemplo;

> Un documento principal main.js

```
  main.js
    metodo(){
    //hace algo
    }
```

> Otro docuemento, utilidad.js, que usa main.js

```
 utilidad.js 
    importo main.js
    //llamo a método de main.js
    metodo()
```

Comment: la pregunta es, para que quieres hacer esto? si tienes ambos .js en tu index.html en uno puedes llamar a funciones del otro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/3045491) de SO en inglés, tienes muchas maneras.

Me parece interesante este, ya que solo importas un método en concreto en vez de todo el archivo:

```
// main.js
export function metodo() {
  return "Hello";
}

// utilidad.js
import {metodo} from 'main.js'; // o './main.js'
let val = metodo(); // val es "Hello";
```

o si quieres el archivo entero, con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) puedes añadir dinámicamente los `scripts`:

```
//utilidades.js
$.getScript("main.js", function(){

   alert("El script se ha cargado pero no necesariamente se ha ejecutado");

});

let val = metodo(); // val es "Hello";
```

Comment: Gracias; :(  me sale  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: @jecuro es porque tu modulo actual no usa  ES6. Usa pues la version de jquery o lee la respuesta en ingles para elegir la que más de interese

Comment: ok lo miro, muchas gracias